# proving $ \mu^T \Sigma \mu \cdot \textbf{1}^T \Sigma \textbf{1} \geq (\textbf{1}^T \Sigma \mu)^2 $

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, bilinear-form, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

how do you prove this :

$$ \mu^T \Sigma \mu \cdot \textbf{1}^T \Sigma \textbf{1} \geq (\textbf{1}^T \Sigma \mu)^2 $$

---

I thought about using C.S. inequality, which yields to :

(writing the matrix $\Sigma$ as $(\sigma_{ij})$ :
$$(\sum \sum \sigma_{ij} u_j )^2 \leq (\sum \sum \sqrt {\sigma_{ij} }^2)  (\sum \sum \sqrt {\sigma_{ij} }^2 u_j^2 ) $$

i don't know what to do next. I'm afraid i'm missing the cross product of $$ u_i u_j$$

I'm sure it is simple and I'm missing a trivial point. Can you please help me ?

Oh and if you can detail a little bit about the equality case. When does it happen here ?

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is positive (semi)-definite, then your inequality *is* the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement as presented is not true for an arbitrary matrix $\Sigma$.  For instance, if we take
$$
\Sigma = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}, \qquad \mu = \pmatrix{1\\0}
$$
then your inequality becomes $0 \geq 1$, which is clearly false.

---

Presumably, you are meant to assume that $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix, which is to say that $\Sigma$ is (symmetric and) positive semidefinite.  With that assumption, one approach is as follows.  To begin, note that there exists a matrix $M$ such that $\Sigma = M^TM$.  It follows that 
$$
\mathbf 1^T \Sigma \mu = \mathbf 1^T M^TM\mu = (M \mathbf 1)^T (M\mu).
$$
It now suffices to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the vectors $x = M \mathbf 1$, $y = M \mu$.

Comment: really good answer, i have to stress this out. Thank you.